# Correct LED driver for 10x 1.5W G4 12V DC bulbs in light fitting

Tags: led

I have a light fitting that fits 10 G4 bulbs. I have bought 10 G4 LED bulbs that require 12V DC and are rated at 1.. They are dimmable. Should I buy a dimmable constant current LED driver or a dimmable constant voltage LED driver?

Comment: I am dealing with the same problem myself. The short answer is, "it depends on the bulb." Some bulbs dim by varying the voltage. Some bulbs dim by varying the current. The only way to know is to get the spec from the manufacturer. Because LEDs are ICs, it really depends on how they were designed. Using the wrong driver or wrong power supply can cause overheating and reduce the life of the LED. What bulb did you get?

Comment: I had light fittings that were designed for G4 bulbs. I bought 12V DC bulbs in the end and I bought Constant Voltage LED drivers for them. They are working great. I have noticed a great deal of variation in quality between manufacturers. I now have a 50W LED driver powering 20x G4 1.5W bulbs (12V DC) in a chandelier. It is silent in operation and light as a feather. The previous halogen driver weighed 1Kg. I bought a 30W LED driver to power 12x 1.5W G4 bulbs (12V DC) and it made a horrible humming sound so I sent it back and got a different brand and that was fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally feel the word "driver" should ONLY be used to describe *constant-current* power sources.  A constant-*voltage* supply is just a "power supply".

The whole point of a **standard** socket is so a variety of fixtures can accommodate bulbs in many styles from many makers.*

When a standard socket exists, the common *lingua franca* of all those various products is a specific voltage -- meaning those sockets will be always driven in "constant Voltage" mode.

Whereas in practice, constant current drivers are matched up to specific series chains of LED emitters.  Because of the precision of that match-up, this is generally done where in custom matched components.  No one has developed a "standard socket" for constant-current LEDs.  I wish they would; the LED emitters themselves are so reliable that the failure point is invariably the constant-current driver.  Wouldn't it be nice if you could change those like bulbs?

The only exception is certain proprietary assemblies such as LED down lights, where the LED and driver are a custom match,  except they provide an inline socket in the wiring to either ease installation or allow different color temperature emitters to be swapped out.

I suppose you could argue that constant-current is as arbitrary as constant-voltage, except that in practice, constant-current power supplies only operate in a limited range of voltages - e.g. 18-44 volts.  Designing a socket that would assure the correct current *and voltage range* matched up would be challenging.